# 'No grant type specified' error when testing OAuth in Stripe

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, stripe-payments

I am testing OAuth process of Stripe in PHP. 
I am able to get `authorization code` in request in landing Page.

But when i do cURL request to get access token from authorization code, I am getting an error, which says `No grant type specified`.

Following is my code for the Landing Page so far:

```
<?php
$authorization_code = $_REQUEST['code'];

$params = array();
$params['grant_type'] = 'authorization_code';
$params['code'] = $authorization_code;

$url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token';

$ch = curl_init();
$header = array ();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('Accept: application/json', 'Content-Length: 0', 'Authorization: Bearer sk_test_secretkey' ) );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
echo $response;
?>
```

And this the error i am getting:

```
{ "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "No grant type specified" }
```

Am i missing something ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to url encode the parameters:

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));`

There's a PHP example in the Stripe Connect docs (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth#sample-code). If you're still having trouble, it might be worth using some kind of HTTP proxy to see what you're *actually* sending over the wire or contacting support@stripe.com.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Got this working few days before, forgot to update here. Anyways Thanks. Cheerrzz!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works fine for me.

```
$params = array();
$params['grant_type'] = 'authorization_code';
$params['code'] = $authorization_code;

$url = 'https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token';

$ch = curl_init();
$header = array ();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
echo $response;
?> <pre>
```